# Running Java program in terminal. raising ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, terminal, compiler-errors

I've created a shell program with java. I'm trying to run the program through terminal. but it keeps on raising ClassNotFoundException. The program runs perfectly fine on IntelliJ but running on terminal causes exceptions.

here is the terminal script I run:

```
javac -d bin/ driver/Shell.java
java -cp bin/ driver.Shell
```

now here is where I get the class.forName and all:
NOTE: classes variable is a Hashtable, mapping a name to a path.

```
    String[] cmd = input.split(" ");

    String commad = classes.get(cmd[0]);
    try{
        Class<?> foundedCommand = java.lang.Class.forName(commad);
        Constructor cons = foundedCommand.getConstructor(String.class);
        Command runCmd = (Command) cons.newInstance(cmd[1]);
```

Running this on Itellij works perfectly fine. but in terminal it ClassNotFoundException. please help

here is the Runner.java class which is invoked by Shell.java

```
package runner;


import commands.Command;
import exceptions.DirectoryExistsException;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Runner {

    private String input;

    private Hashtable<String, String> classes = new Hashtable<String, String>
            (){
        {
            put("mkdir", "commands.MakeDirectory");
        }
    };

    public Runner(){}

    public Runner(String input){
        this.input = input;
    }

    public String[] runCommand(){
        String[] cmd = input.split(" ");

        String commad = classes.get(cmd[0]);
        try{
            Class<?> foundedCommand = java.lang.Class.forName(commad);
            Constructor cons = foundedCommand.getConstructor(String.class);
            Command runCmd = (Command) cons.newInstance(cmd[1]);
            return runCmd.run();

        }
        catch (DirectoryExistsException e){
            return new String[]{"", e.getMessage()};
        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            return new String[]{"", e.getMessase()};
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e){
            return new String[]{"", e.getMessase()};
        }
        catch (InstantiationException e){
            return new String[]{"", e.getMessase()};
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e){
            return new String[]{"", e.getMessase()};}
        catch (InvocationTargetException e){
            return new String[]{"", e.getMessase()};}

    }
}
```

And here is the Shell.java class:

```
package driver;


import logger.ConsoleLog;
import runner.Runner;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shell {

    public void runShell(){
        ConsoleLog log = new ConsoleLog();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        log.printPromptMessage();
        String uI = input.nextLine();

        while(!uI.equals("exit")){

            Runner run = new Runner(uI);
            String[] output = run.runCommand();

            if(!output[0].equals("")){
                log.setPromptMessage(output[0]);
            }
            log.printOutput(output[1]);
            log.printPromptMessage();
            uI = input.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("exiting Shell");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shell shell = new Shell();
        shell.runShell();
    }

}
```

ConsoleLog basically System.out.print() the things.
and here is the error in the terminal:

```
/# mkdir /Users/KevinMacbook/Documents/CSC207/exercises/test
commands.MakeDirectory
```

Here is the trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: commands.MakeDirectory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at runner.Runner.runCommand(Runner.java:35)
    at driver.Shell.runShell(Shell.java:20)
    at driver.Shell.main(Shell.java:35)
```

Comment: Please post the entire output of the error and the entire Shell class. What is package is Command? What are the contents of your bin directory?

Comment: What is in string command when you run from Itellij vs command line?

Comment: Check what libraries are loaded in IDE.

Comment: i've made changes in the question

Comment: Base on the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html you are setting the classpath incorrectly. Should be something like this: java -classpath commands;runner driver.Shell

Comment: And I think it would be easier to package your source into a JAR file, and run that.

Comment: run the jar file through terminal?